How to make this window sill water tight
This vinyl replacement window was installed but now I need to make this window sill water tight. What do I need to do? The window was ordered and it was the wrong size, so the 2x4 was put in to compensate. I understand the rough opening should have been flashed during install, but it did not happen. So, just looking for a good optio that is water tight.


Sills need to drain water outwards. The wrong approach to "water-tight" can ensure that you rot out the wall and get to have another go at fixing it. If it wasn't flashed at install reinstalling now or reinstalling after the wall rots might be your options...


Wrap the various sill components with aluminum. This requires a "bending brake", a large tool for precisely bending sheet metal.

Caulk seams where necessary. Ideally, the wrap itself drains water properly, but caulk can be used sparingly for appearance and to add a layer of protection. No joint should rely only on caulk.

Deal with the siding, flashing, and house wrap. I can't see much in your photo, but water draining off the sill wrap needs to be managed. Caulking to the siding is inappropriate. What's behind the siding deals with rain.



And make sure there's a slope on the sill—hard to tell from pic due to angles and perspective.
